# How to access primary constructor variable inside a function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, constructor

As per leetcode problem [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-query-immutable/) following snippet of code is provided

```
class NumArray(nums: IntArray) {

fun sumRange(i: Int, j: Int): Int {
    
}
```

}

Now to access the nums array inside `fun sumRange` I have modified the snippet like below:

```
    class NumArray(nums: IntArray) {

    // added line below
    var _nums = nums

    fun sumRange(i: Int, j: Int): Int {
        
    }
}
```

With this I am able to access _nums inside sumRange() and I wanted to ask if there is some other way to directly access the `nums` variable inside the class method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a more succinct way! You can declare a `val` or `var` directly as part of the primary constructor. Try changing your constructor to this:

```kotlin
class NumArray(val nums: IntArray) {
    ...
```